# Binding data of multiple classes to single list view/xamarin forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, data-binding, portable-class-library, shared-project

Hello how can i bind data of multiple classes to a single list view through xaml. I sucessfully bind data from single class to a lisview but when i try to bind data of more than one classes it didn't show anything in xaml.

Comment: Can you please provide a snippet from the xaml and the ViewModels you trying to bind to?

Answer (score 1):

You cant't do that 'directly'.
As all `UIElement` controls have only one `BindingContext` property, you can bind only one objet at a time.

In MVVM patterns, you implement ViewModel classes to group all the needed data to display on the associated page...

So for your 'Listview', I suggest you to **make a property in your ViewModel that references a new object that is simply the [aggregation](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/difference-between-composition-and-aggregation/)** of all classes you want to connect to your listview.

A simple exemple:

```
/// Data A needed for your listview 
public class DataA { ... }

/// Data B needed for your listview 
public class DataB { ... }

///
/// You will make a property of this type into your viewModel
///
public class ListviewAggregatedData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private DataA _listviewDataPart1;
    private DataB _listviewDataPart2;

    public DataA ListViewDataPart1
    {
        get => _listviewDataPart1;
        set {  _listviewDataPart1 = value; PropertyChanged?.Invoke(...); }
    }

    public DataA ListViewDataPart2
    {
        get => _listviewDataPart2;
        set {  _listviewDataPart2 = value; PropertyChanged?.Invoke(...); }
    }

    // ....
}
```

And **in your xaml**, presuming your viewModel implements a property of type `ListviewAggregatedData` called 'VmAggregatedDataProp', You could have something like that:

```
        <ListView
            BindingContext="{Binding VmAggregatedDataProp}"
            Header="{Binding ListViewDataPart1.Title}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding ListViewDataPart2.AllMyItems}"
            />
```

Binding names in this example must be replaced by your own properties...
Tell me if it s clear...

Comment: You are right here But my point is i'm getting data through xml and store this in classes of shared project and i'm accessing this data through viewmodel and i'm unable to acess class B from shared project in my xaml.

Comment: I'm using shared project for my classes to get,set data and now i'm getting data from one of my shared class through view model. But i'm unable to display data from other class of shared project and i'm using MVVM approach.